# Metric for an electromagnetic plane wave in Cartesian coordinates, Rosen coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, coordinate-systems

I would like to know what Rosen coordinates are and how they transform to Cartesian coordinates, I have been unsuccessful in my efforts to determine this. I want to write the metric for an electromagnetic plane wave in Cartesian coordinates.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromatic_electromagnetic_plane_wave#Optical_effects

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Quoting the top of the page you linked to, ,"In general relativity, the monochromatic electromagnetic plane wave spacetime is the analog of the monochromatic plane waves known from Maxwell's theory. The precise definition of the solution is quite complicated, but very instructive." Why do you think you can find Cartesian coordinates covering this spacetime?

Comment: Well they might have been referring to the fact that it contains a Mathieu cosine. I also added the "if at all possible" bit to show I'm not sure it's possible. Why do you think it's helpful to ask rhetorical question like this?

Comment: Perhaps  you just want to write $u$ and $v$ as $u=z-t$ and $v=z+t$ so $du\,dv$ becomes $dz^2-dt^2$?  This is surely the closest one can come to Cartesians, as Cartesians only exist in flat space.

Comment: Cartesian coordinates do not just exist in flat space. Expecting the metric to be able to be expressed in Cartesian coördinates does NOT mean assuming the spacetime to be flat. Assuming that the Pythagorean theorem holds in these coordinates, however, would be. These two things are not the same. Think about it for a second: can the Schwarzschild metric be given in Cartesian coordinates? Yes it can! Does this imply that the Schwarzschild spacetime is flat? Anyway, Mike, so you are saying those $z$ and $t$ are the usual Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @mikestone perhaps you mean $u=t-z$? Otherwise I get a positive $dt^2$ due to the minus sign in front of the $dudv$.